# Show "Show-Button" after Jquery function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use this, it refreshes my whole page and there is "Show" :

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#book").hide("slow", function() {
    document.body.innerHTML ='Show';
  });
});
```

How can I prevent the whole page refresh I just want to add the line: Show?

Comment: Is it possible that your #clickme element is a button with the type attribute set to submit?

Comment: it's because it's either `#clickme` is an anchor or a button/input type of submit.

Comment: It´s just a div element.

Comment: I tried this:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     '$("body").append("<div class='uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body' style='z-index: 980;height:520px;' uk-sticky='bottom: #offset' id='book'>Show</div>");'

Comment: I did .html instead of .append. It seems to work now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put a span element with an id and update the value of that span.

```
  $("#span-id").html("");
  $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
   $( "#book" ).hide( "slow", function() {
     $("#span-id").html("Show");
   });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `append` method if you need to append text to the body or to an element.

```
$("body").append("Show");
```

Comment: I have a sticky element on top in which i want the "Show-Button" to place. How can i do this?

Comment: @AndreasSchwaiger Add an empty div element on place where your button should appear. Then give it an id, like id="here". Use "#here" instead of "body": $("#here").append("Show");

Comment: Select the sticky element instead of the body in the solution

Comment: But then the sticky element has already a height and the user can see it, i would need something like: If the hide button isnt clicked, height of sticky element = 0px. If he clicks show again, sticky element is 0px.

Comment: Sounds like another question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your clickme element is a button so it cause a refreshing on the page. Try something rather than a button, e.g div. See below code and working js fiddle demo below.

Sample Html;

```
<body>
<div id="book">
some books here
</div>
<div id="clickme">
click here
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript code. I am assuming you have already referenced jQuery file.

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).hide( "slow", function() {
$("body").append("<p>Show</p>")

  });
});
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qx3p578o/

Comment: `<div id="clickme">
  Hide
</div>`    This is what i had before. Its just a div container.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `callback` function. `$(selector).hide('slow', callback)`. More details [Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#clickme").click(function() {
      $("#test").hide("slow", function() {
        $('#load').html('<p>Show</p>');
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="clickme">Click on it</p>
<div id="load"></div>
<p id="test">Paragraph with id attributes</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add paragraph, its look like:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#book").hide("slow", function() {
    $("body").append("<p>Show</p>");
  });
});
```

and check if 'clickme' button isn't type="submit"